# How can I type "ç" in Windows GTK apps?

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, language, pidgin, gtk

I use an English (US) international keyboard layout, and every time I use the key <kbd>´</kbd> followed by <kbd>c</kbd> it yields the Portuguese and French character "ç" (cedilla), which is desirable. However in GTK apps (Pidgin for instance) it yields "ć", which is Polish.

**How can I make GTK apps behave the same way as the rest of the apps do?**

NOTE: I had the same problem on Ubuntu [11.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59663/how-to-type-c-when-using-usa-intl-as-the-keyboard-layout) and [10.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14202/how-to-use-an-input-language-different-from-the-keyboard-layout-country-and-from), and they found two sets of solutions that work on those specific versions.

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here, I would recommend flagging your question and having it moved to http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Max I don't understand how a question about Windows would be helped there

Comment: Unless I missed it, "Windows" wasn't in the title before Gareth edited it.

Comment: @Max it was always there

Comment: I don't use GTK on Windows, but have you tried to search for a file named "gtk.immodules" ? If it exists, the [above link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/59663/how-to-type-c-when-using-usa-intl-as-the-keyboard-layout) you gave might still work.

Comment: @JaderDias: Have you tried right-clicking the relevant text box, choosing **Input Methods -> Cedilla** ?

Comment: @James I didn't know about that. I tried and it works. The problem is that I have to do that every time I open a new chat window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that GTK apps do not integrate with the Windows input <strike>Method Editor (IME)</strike> language settings and instead use their own. By default this is set to *Simple* and needs to be changed. You need to create a new system-wide environment variable called **GTK_IM_MODULE** and set it to **cedilla** (I wrongly thought that when set to *ime* GTK would emulate Windows own behaviour but IME is a different thing). I got the name of the environment variable from here: http://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/4896

Comment: `ime` doesn't work exactly like windows ime. to make the cedilla work I had to use `cedilla`. Capitalizing it (`Cedilla`) didn't work.

Comment: Glad you got it working in the end. I updated my post to clarify my mistake.