# Windows Pidgin GTK+ cannot type quotes properly

Tags: keyboard-layout, pidgin, input-languages, gtk-windows

I use Pidgin, XChat and MonoDevelop on my windows 7 machine. 
Since a year, more or less, im not able to type quotes:
" becomes ¨
' becomes ´

I've finally started to get really pissed at this problem and i wanted to fix it. Ive spend some time on googling for a solution and the closest i got was [How can I type "ç" in Windows GTK apps?](https://superuser.com/questions/335141/how-can-i-type-c-in-windows-gtk-apps). I have changed these system variables and even manually changed the input methods but without success.

Whenever i change it to Cedilla the quotes are still the same ( ¨ instead of "). When i change it to Windows IME i dont get characters at all (typing " will not even get me a character, not even a whitespace). All other characters (a b c d) do appear.

Im sure im not the only one facing this problem and i hope someone else has found a working solution.

Many thanks in advance!
Roberto

Comment: You are definitely not the only one and it's quite annoying, especially if you're typing in a language that frequently require those characters (and that includes English). Strangely enough i don't remember this bug happening on Windows 7. Only Windows 8.